# What percent of current Americans have ancestors that had slaves in the US in the past?

Tags: united-states, demographics, reference-request, data-sources

I am researching the current political debate about reparations.  What percentage of living Americans have ancestors that had slaves in the US in the past?

Is there any data on this or is there research available on this subject?

Comment: I am pretty sure that some have both slaves and slave-owners in their ancestry. Also, I suppose you want to refer to only slavery in the US, not some immigrant from Italy or Greece and slaves in the classic era?

Comment: Yes I am researching only US

Comment: Given that an awful lot of white slaveowners raped and impregnated their black slaves, the answer will probably include most of the black population of the USA.